# Javascript applied CSS3 transitions not working on new element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm using a mixture of CSS/JS to create some simple page slide transitions for new pages, that will eventually be loaded dynamically by AJAX, however on creation of the new element "main2" which has the necessary -webkit-transition etc. it does not slide in like it should, but simply appears. The previous page however slides out fine, using basically the same code.

As well as this, changing the slide in to after the animation for the previous page has finished like so:

```
function newPage() {
    var newMain = document.createElement("div");
    newMain.className = "main";
    newMain.style.left = "100vw";
    newMain.id = "main2";
    newMain.style.zIndex = 1999;
    newMain.style.background = "#AAA";
    document.body.appendChild(newMain);
    oldMain = document.getElementById("main");
    oldMain.style.left = "-50vw";

    setTimeout(function() {
        newMain.style.left = "50vw";
        oldMain.parentNode.removeChild(oldMain);
        newMain.id = "main";
    }, 1000);
}
```

makes it animate in, just not at the right time.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's just something glaringly simple that I've missed.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5raj05th/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5raj05th/8/

I changed the code so you do trigger the transition by adding the style:

```
newMain.style.left = "100vw";
```

and later:

```
newMain.style.left = "0";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I was trying for was for both the animations to happen at once, so it goes straight from main - newMain if you know what I mean? Sorry if I didn't make it clear

Comment: Then try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5raj05th/9/ I think the problem you stumbled upon was that transition does not trigger if you manipulate the DOM, and add something else _immediatly_ after that. Therefore the 2nd small timeout (but there are other techniques as well for this). Btw: it's better to use the "transitionend" event if you want to clear up after an transition ends than relying on a timeout.

Comment: Ah great thanks, I'll change it to that, what else other than a timeout can be used to fix that?

Comment: 1) using requestAnimationFrame 2) invalidating Layout before setting new class / attributes, eg with this line: `newMain.clientWidth;` (see also: http://jsfiddle.net/5raj05th/10/)